# RRDtool: Separate and sum datasources with RRD files

Tags: rrdtool

I have a .RRD file in with an old statistics and I want to separate one datasource and add to the new statistics. 
These 2 RRD are in the same format but with different names of datasources and different time of creation.

How can I separate a datasource from 1 old file? Then how to sum to the other datasource in new file?

Answer (score 0):

Does rrdjig help?

- https://lists.oetiker.ch/pipermail/rrd-developers/2010-March/003661.html
- http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool-trac/browser/trunk/contrib/rrdjig/rrdjig.pl

From the announcement,

> In a project for init7 [edited url out] I have implemented rrdjig. This
>   tool can populate an rrd file based on the data found in an existing
>   rrd. It recreates an aproximation of the original data stream and
>   feeds it into the destination rrd file using rrdtool update. With this
>   method it is possible to do arbitrary rrd format conversions.

Comment: Thank you, It's worked but I discover that my .rrd files have different datastructures.